# Where-Object filtering - Alternative to multiple and

Tags: powershell

Using `PowerCLI` to filter a list of virtual machines:

```
Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne 'VM1001' -and $_.Name -ne 'VM2002' -and $_.Name -ne 'VM3003' -and $_.Name -ne 'VM4004'} | Select_Object ...
```

Is there a cleaner/better way to filter results? This would improve script readability.

Thanks

Comment: `$_.Name -notin 'VM1001','VM2002','VM3003','VM4004'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @JosefZ commented, using the `-notin` is good for PowerShell version 3 and later:

```
Get-VM | Where-Object { $_.Name -notin @('VM1001','VM2002','VM3003','VM4004') }
```

On PowerShell version 2, you can still can use the `-notcontains` [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1):

```
$Excluded = @('VM1001','VM2002','VM3003','VM4004')
Get-VM | Where-Object { $Excluded -notcontains $_.Name }
```